# Calling a function to get JSON bject before app.module.ts Loads (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

My app.module.ts file is :-

```
import { MsalModule, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import getConfig from './env';
var config_values = getConfig(); // we are calling the function here, but it takes time to complete
console.log("here",config_values);

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ...
    ...
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: config_values,// we want the json values here which are returned by the above function.
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set to true for Internet Explorer 11
      },
    }, {
      popUp: !isIE,
      consentScopes: [
        'user.read',
        'openid',
        'profile',
      ],
      unprotectedResources: [],
      protectedResourceMap: [
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
      ],
      extraQueryParameters: {}
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide : HTTP_INTERCEPTORS , useClass : htt, multi : true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass: MsalInterceptor,multi: true},
    GlobalsService
  ],
  bootstrap: [component]
})
export class AppModule {

 }
```

And the Environment.ts file is:-

```
export function getConfig() {​​​​​
    try{
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var config;
    request.open('GET',"URL", false);
    request.send(null);

    if (request.status === 200) {​​​​​
        console.log(request.responseText);
        config = request.responseText;
    }​​​​​
    return JSON.parse(config);
}

    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

export default getConfig;
```

As its a external call it takes time to get the data, but the module loads before and throws an error, So we want a solution in which either it waits for the external data to be loaded or loads after getting the data and the SSO works fine.
we want to get the config values before the file loads.
Can anyone Help Please!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `platformBrowserDynamic` to dynamically fetch configuration values for MSAL. See: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v1-docs/configuration.md#platformbrowserdynamic

Comment: Hey @jasonnutter actually we don't want to hardcode the values, rather we want to fetch it from a cloud function, so is that possible in anyway?

Comment: The documentation uses fetch to acquire a hard-coded JSON file as a proof-of-concept, but you can replace that fetch call with a fetch call to any other API, such as to a cloud function.

Comment: Thankyou so much! @jasonnutter